# How to implement javascript code on back4app.com in objective c

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, parse-platform, back4app

I want to get "ServerDate" on back4app.com using PFCloud. Currently I am facing the below issue:

> Invalid function: "getServerDate" (Code: 141, Version: 1.13.0)
>   When i used below code:

```
  [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"getServerDate"
   withParameters:nil block:^(id object, NSError *error)
   {
      if (!error)
      {

          NSLog(@"%@",serverDate);
      }
      else
      {
          [self getServerCurrentDate];
      }
   }];
```

I am beginner Please Explain How to implement and get javascript code on objective c?

Comment: What is `serverDate`?

Comment: Show me your Cloud code

Answer (score 1):

Error you getting is becasue you don't have a function in your `main.js` file called `"getServerDate"`.

Make sure you have it defined correctly as follows in your `main.js` file:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getServerDate", function(request,response){

//Your javascript logic comes here and return the server date to the response

});
```